# how to convert google app ui into html service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not a developer but can assemble code snippets but I can't seem to convert this code which reads all tab names in a sheet, except those noted, presents them in a dialog, when clicked, navigates to that tab.  This is useful because my sheet has many tabs.

How can I get the all sheets array into a clickable grid in a modal dialog?

```js
function showGoToSheet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Go to sheet...")
    .setHeight(550).setWidth(310);
  var sPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)
    .setSize(440, 600);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize(650, 400);
  var fTable = app.createFlexTable().setCellPadding(1).setSize(600, 310)
    .setCellSpacing(0).setBorderWidth(1); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();   
  var goToSheetClick = app.createServerHandler('handleGoToSheetClick');     
  for (var i=0, iLen=allsheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    if (sheet_name != 'ActivityLog' && sheet_name != 'AllData' && sheet_name != 'Scratch' && sheet_name != 'Data Validation'){
    //Add to Console
    fTable.setWidget(i, 0, app.createButton(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name)
      .setWidth(300).addClickHandler(goToSheetClick)); 
    }
  }

  app.add(sPanel.add(vPanel.add(fTable)));
  ss.show(app);
}

function handleGoToSheetClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.source).activate();
  app.close();   
  return app; 
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)  i.e. show attempts and specific coding issues to make a valid question on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

UiApp has been deprecated so here's how I would do it.

If you want the dialog to go away after each sheet click then inside the loop change the S += line to this:

```
s += '<input type="button" value="Go to: ' + sheet_name + '" onClick="google.script.run.getMySheet(\'' + sheet_name + '\');google.script.host.close();" /><br />';
```

It will do google.script.run.getMySheet() first and then google.script.host.close();

```
function showGoToSheet() {

  var allsheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
  var s = '<style>#mySheets{padding:10px;}</style><div id="mySheets">';
  for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) 
  {
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    if (sheet_name != 'ActivityLog' && sheet_name != 'AllData' && sheet_name != 'Scratch' && sheet_name != 'Data Validation')
    {
      s += '<input id="btn' + i +'" type="button" value="Go to: ' + sheet_name + '" onClick="google.script.run.getMySheet(\'' + sheet_name + '\');" /><br />';
    }
  }
  s += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /></div>';
  dispStatus('My Sheets',s,300,400);
}

function getMySheet(shtname)
{
  var shtname = typeof(shtname) !== 'undefined' ? shtname : ''; 
  if(!shtname)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid Parameter in function getMySheet.');
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtname).activate();
  }
}
```

This can be modeless or modal.  Your choice.  I prefer modeless so it's modeless. You can change the style of the div#mySheets to anything you want and each button has a unique id 'btn' + i.

```
// Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
function dispStatus(title,html,width,height,modal)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 400;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var modal = typeof(modal) !== 'undefined' ? modal : false;
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 if(!modal)
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
 else
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly and gave me something to follow for future functionality!

Comment: Good deal.  Glad to help.